# Wrap text in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have a text variable and I need to wrap the text:

My code:

```js
var text = "Test test test test test test";
                
            function typing(){
                if(i<text.length){
                    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    setTimeout(typing,50);
                }
            }
            typing();
```

How can I wrap this text? I print `i` with an `innerHTML`, but I need to wrap the text like `br` in html.

Comment: What do you mean with wrapping the text like `<br>` in html? Does an `<br>` needed to be placed every space? Or do you want the `<br>` to be added on an line end `\n` in the text.

Comment: Just make the element with id="text" less wide using css?  It should wrap by itself.

Comment: My code is a write text animation, but i need to wrap this text because is too long

Answer (score 1):

Just use  `width` in css, everything is working out of the box.

I recommend to use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` when it's done.

```js
var text = "Test test test test test test";
var i = 0;                
function typing(){
    if (i<text.length) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typing,50);
        }
    }
typing();
```

```css
#text{
    width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `<br>` tag after X number of chars:

```js
const text = 'Text text text text text text text'
const maxchars = 12;

let i = 0;

function typing(){
  if (i < text.length) {
    const char = text.charAt(i);
    let addChar = char;

    // Breaks the text at the max length of chars
    if ((i % maxchars) === maxchars -1) {
      addChar += '<br>';
    }
    
    // Getting the element that has the id text
    const element = document.getElementById("text")
    
    // Adding the char to the element
    element.innerHTML += addChar;

    i++;
    setTimeout(typing,50);
  }
}

typing();
```

```html
<p id='text'></p>
```

However I do recommend creating some extra logic that will look up the previous space and break there for not words breaking halfway in.

Comment: My code is a write text animation, but i need to wrap this text because is too long